Copy data from AWS SQL database to Azure SQL database (without using a data gateway?)
I have an SQL database that someone else is managing in an AWS instance. It requires me to connect to a VPN to access (from my personal computer).
I want to create a daily job that will copy a table to my own Azure SQL database. Given the relationship with team managing the AWS instance, it does not seem realistic to get them to make any infrastructural changes that would help facilitate the copying of the data into our own database.
Is there a realistic way to perform some sort of copy operation from the AWS sql database to my Azure instance?
I have looked into Azure Data factory, Azure VM  and Azure Logic apps, but from my research it appears that there is an expectation of a gateway to make the data accessible.
Am I looking at this problem in the wrong way? Is there a way I can just write a script/operation that will have this job run in the cloud daily that could resolve to a single or reasonable range of IP addresses that could be whitelisted on the AWS database?
Trying to understand what the best practice is here or if this is even achievable.

Maybe the AWS team can automate the process to export the AWS database as bacpac and upload it to an Azure Storage Account.
You can then automate the import of the bacpac from the Azure Storage Account (Using PowerShell and Azure Automation) into the bacpac into an Azure SQL logical server but taking in consideration the workarounds explained here. Only use this option if you have renamed the "admin" user at the source Amazon RDS for SQL Server instance.

Appreciate this and will consider this as an option. My main goal was to be able to set up some kind of job without any input or changes from the AWS side aside from potentially whitelisting more IPs. Based on the nature of the workaround you're providing, do you think that is realistic at all

Yeah it is realistic. You provide the Azure Storage account name and key to the AWS team and they should be able to create a job or schedule a task to put an export of the AWS database on the Azure Storage account. On the Azure side, you can use PowerShell and Azure Automation account to automate the process of importing the bacpac to an Azure SQL Database logical server. It is not an invasive procedure.
